# Flask Bootstrap modal works on dev server, but not in production

Tags: python, flask, modal-dialog

Does anyone face this issue.. I have a very strange behavior with Flask and Bootstrap modal. On my dev server `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` I have a modal which appears after user is typing wrong login credentials:

HTML code in Index page:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ExistsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">This email already exists!</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              If you have forgotten your password, .......
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Continue</button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

But on my production 'http://flask-env.xxx.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com I can see the modal only if I manually refresh a page!

For return function I'm using 
`return redirect(url_for('index',_anchor='login'))` and in `index()` I passed arguments!

```
{% if email_exists %}
          <script>
            $("#ExistsModal").modal('show');
          </script>
          {% endif %}
```

My question is - why modal show up after manual refresh on production? But on dev its works fine!

Comment: Is the HTML code send to the client as expected?

Comment: On dev server yes !

Comment: That is not HTML code and the dev server it not the problem.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you please give more details ? Dev server is not a problem, the problem is production server !

Comment: So, when the dev server is not the problem why are you answering "On dev server yes"? Talk about the server that does **not** work!

Comment: Are you sure the variable `email_exists` actually exists on the prod server and is being returned to your template? Maybe it's empty for some reason until you refresh. Put a simple paragraph tag with some text inside of that if statement to see if it's being evaluated or not. Maybe it's empty when being returned from the back end

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the var `email_exists` is empty! But why its working properly on dev? and on production its empty?
Any server restrictions ? Configuration ?