# Can't link button to modal window

Tags: python, html, flask

I am following along with the answer to this question: [Modal window in Jinja2 template. Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606429/modal-window-in-jinja2-template-flask)

I've made the following snippet in page.html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="placeholder-id">Test Modal</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="placeholder-id" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal Stuff</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The button shows up, but nothing happens when I click it. I can't tell if I'm just supposed to make `data-target` match `id` or if I need to do something else.

Alternately, this is just an intermediate step so I can understand the basics of how it's supposed to work.  What I ultimately want to do is separate this out, so that clicking the button allows me to load a blueprint in python to make a modal window pop up.

What I would like is to have something like:

in page.html:

```
<!-- not sure what that something would be -->
<button something="{{ url_for('sandbox/some_path') }}">Test Modal</button>
```

in sandbox.py:

```
@bp.route('/some_path')                                                                                               
def dosomethingwithmodal():                                                                                           
    data = None                                                                                                       
    return render_template('generate_modal.html', data=data)
```

and finally in generate_modal.html:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="placeholder-id" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal Stuff</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

What do I need to do to alter this pattern to make it work?

Comment: One thing to watch for, if you are using Bootstrap 5, any `data-` attributes need to be changed to `data-bs-`. (Example, `data-target` -> `data-bs-target`.)

Comment: It looks like I'm using 4.3.1 (via https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js) so that shouldn't be an issue, but that's good to know!

Comment: In your button on page.html, try changing ` data-target="placeholder-id"` to ` data-target="#placeholder-id"`.

Comment: @Patrick Yoder That was it!  Okay so as a follow-up, could I replace that with "{{ url_for('something') }}" (possibly with a # in the beginning, although it looks like that would be handled within url_for()?)to let python separately handle the inputs to the modal and create a separate blueprint?  Or would that be better as a separate question? Either way, if you pop this into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your button that leads to the modal in page.html. You have:

```
<button ... data-target="placeholder-id">Test Modal</button>
```

But it should be:

```
<button ... data-target="#placeholder-id">Test Modal</button>
```

The `#` is needed to correctly point to the modal.